# Azure app service set quotas for cpu and ram

Tags: azure, azure-appservice, azure-app-service-plans

Is it possible to set a quota (or a limit) for how much cpu and ram usage a azure app service can use?

Let's say I have one app service plan `plan-one` and two app services running on that plan, `A` and `B`. Can I somehow say that `A` is only allowed to use 70% of the cpu and 50% of the ram?

Comment: There seems to be no policy or limit to restrict at each app level. see this [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans?source=recommendations#should-i-put-an-app-in-a-new-plan-or-an-existing-plan), it gives an idea of max apps that can be accommodated in each of the app service plan SKU. All apps in an ASP shares the compute[VM] resources, what you are asking for could be a nice feature!

Comment: @Aband Please turn your comment into an answer as you are correct.

Answer (score -2):

> Azure app service set quotas for cpu and ram:

**Check the below given points:**

- Check file system usage by webapp by visiting `webapp -> Quotas`

  [image]

  **Note**: After my workaround here, there is no restriction policy or limit for each app level as described [in MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans?source=recommendations#should-i-put-an-app-in-a-new-plan-or-an-existing-plan).
- There is a resource quota limit on the Azure Website that is applicable to either the Free or Shared scale modes. When accessing your Azure website, you may encounter "**Error 403 - This web app is stopped**" if the website has hit its resource quota limit, which can be achieved in either the Free or Shared scale options.
  [AzureWebsites Online-tools](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about/)
- You can check by visiting metrics under appserviceplan to retrieve the CPU usage. Memory(ram) as well as other related metrics.

[image]

- Check the CPU Usage as well as memory analysis by visiting website that exists in your appserviceplan:

```
 Diagnose and solve problems -> Availability and Performance -> High CPU Analysis
```

[image]

- Every time when you build an azure website, you also get a "SCM" (site control manager) which is utilized for administration and debugging.
  you can access it as shown below:
  Eg: If I have webapp like
  `https://< webapp >.azurewebsites.net` then SCM site will be
  `https://< webapp >.scm.azurewebsites.net`

[image]

You can also check what are all the processes running on "azurewebsite".

[Appservice Plan Cost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans?source=recommendations#how-much-does-my-app-service-plan-cost)